# .NET: How to manage application settings?

Tags: .net, app-config, application-settings

i've created some **Application** settings (i.e. not **User**) settings in my Visual Studio project:

[image]

This application will be running from a shared (i.e. read-only, network) location. How do i alter the application settings? e.g.

- **DefaultServer**: `fvirm001`
- **DatabasePassword**: `QnV0IHNoZSdzIGluIGxvdmUgd2l0aCBzb21lb25lIGVsc2Uu`

In the olden days (last Thursday) i would create a `MyApp.ini` file (in the same folder as `MyApp.exe`), and read the settings from there.

In the new XML .NET world i might change it to `MyApp.xml`. But then i remembered that .NET already has an XML file to store application settings. (e.g. [the customer might want to manage the set of trace listeners in app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010255/net-tracing-what-is-the-default-listener)).

How do i manage the `<applicationSettings>` in `app.config`?

[image]

Can i simply create an `app.config` file in the application directory, and .NET will use values as an override?

Microsoft's MSDN page on [Managing Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9db58th%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) does not mention how to manage application settings.

Comment: Are you talking about changing them, as the developer (e.g. using a new connection string when you migrate databases)? Or are you talking about reading/writing settings at runtime (you mention "the customer")?

Comment: i mean as "the customer", e.g. customer's IT being able to twiddle a value to point to a new server. And the customer being able to alter the database password as they desire.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want are the User settings, which expose the values with `set` and `get` properties and a `Save()` method. You don't have to worry about the XML implementation at all. Why are you adamant about using the Application type?

Comment: IT would have no way to call `.Save()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the values in the Settings designer window you have open. But yes, they're stored in the config file (`ProgramExecutable.exe.config`).

Application Settings are not designed to be changed by the user, so there's no way to change them at runtime (unlike User settings, which can be reassigned and saved).

Comment: Oh, it's tricky. If you do not deploy the `ProgramExecutable.exe.config` the settings are still stored somewhere internally. But if you then place the `.config` file in the folder the application will use the settings from there. So the answer is to place an `MyApp.exe.config` file in the folder, and IT can fiddle with the settings in that text file.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`Reload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.reload.aspx) method of the `ApplicationSettingsBase` class...

Once you update the settings (either manually or from your UI) you'll have to use this method to reload the settings from the config file.

> Reload contrasts with Reset in that the former will load the last set
>   of saved application settings values, whereas the latter will load the
>   saved default values.

Comment: Doesn't really apply to me (as i would just tell everyone to close and reopen the software to pick up the new settings). But +1 for mentioning `Reload` - for whatever intended use it serves.