# Is Trace.WriteLine thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, trace

I have a multithreaded program for which I'd like to use the Trace.WriteLine, and redirect the output to a text file:

```
_LogTracer = new System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener(logPath);   
Trace.AutoFlush = true;
Trace.Listeners.Add(_LogTracer);
```

Is this sufficient to be thread safe? What if two threads are trying to write to the output file at the same time?

Comment: Could you not at least read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx) first? "This type is thread safe."

Comment: "Thread-safe" is not a very good description because typically it will at most ensure the program will not crash if more than one thread mucks around with shared data structures, as well as the type have certain expectations that will still hold in a multithreaded environment. It says very little about the *behavior* other than that. For instance, what would you expect multiple calls to `Trace.Write` to behave like? Always be together in the final output? Can they be split up by another thread managing to write something in between?

Answer (score 4):

{wrt. overall thread-safety}

Using `Trace.Listeners.Add` (or `Remove`) is *not* thread-safe with respect to `Trace.Write` (or `WriteLine`) when [`Trace.UseGlobalLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.usegloballock(v=vs.110).aspx) is explicitly disabled.

The threadsafety - or lack of - for `Write` applies only the individual trace listener type (as noted the TextWriterTraceListener implementation is thread safe) or as guarded via the global trace lock (see [`TraceListener.IsThreadSafe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.isthreadsafe(v=vs.110).aspx) for a discussion).

I've some janky old code that modifies the Listener collection that can result in errors in a multithreaded environment:

```
[System.InvalidOperationException]
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
-------------------------------------------------- -- >
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.ArrayListEnumeratorSimple.MoveNext()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.WriteLine(String message, String category)
```

The documentation says `Listeners` is thread-safe and it is slightly misleading: `Listeners.GetEnumerator` does *not* establish a lock-over-copy as hinted. The thread-safe lock is acquired only over a few individual Add/Remove methods.

To make `Trace.Write` thread-safe with respect to *modifying* `Listeners` requires the use of [`Trace.UseGlobalLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.usegloballock(v=vs.110).aspx) which will acquire the lock over *enumerating and writing to all* listeners.

Comment: Which source code with good patterns using `Trace.Listeners.Add(_LogTracer);` ? using ***lock*** ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41115500/206730

***`Heavily threaded code started blocking for upwards of 12 seconds (!!) on the Trace.WriteLine as it had to acquire the lock over the "trivial" work in the DefaultTraceListener`.***

Comment: So it "is" thread-safe :D -- None of our systems use the default writer and explicitly disable locking, except for the _brief_ moment of modifying listeners.

Answer (score -2):

The test below proves that using `TextWriterTraceListener` is thread safe if used via `Trace` object. Tested in .net6

First, the code from the library, where we see that listener is locked if it is not a thread safe listener.

```
foreach (TraceListener listener in TraceInternal.Listeners)
{
  if (!listener.IsThreadSafe)
  {
    lock (listener)
    {
      listener.TraceEvent(eventCache, TraceInternal.AppName, eventType, id, format, args);
      if (TraceInternal.AutoFlush)
        listener.Flush();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    listener.TraceEvent(eventCache, TraceInternal.AppName, eventType, id, format, args);
    if (TraceInternal.AutoFlush)
      listener.Flush();
  }
}
```

Unit test

```cs
Trace.Listeners.Clear();

Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener("C:\\temp\\TEMP-\\mylog.log"));

var rand = new Random();
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var t1 = Task.Run(() => Write(sw, "Thread#1", rand));
var t2 = Task.Run(() => Write(sw, "Thread#2", rand));
var t3 = Task.Run(() => Write(sw, "Thread#3", rand));
var t4 = Task.Run(() => Write(sw, "Thread#4", rand));
var t5 = Task.Run(() => Write(sw, "Thread#5", rand));

Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5);

Trace.Close();
//-----------
static void Write(Stopwatch sw, string threadName, Random rand)
{
    while(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < 30)
    {
        int ms = rand.Next(10, 20);
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ms); -- no slow down process
        Trace.TraceInformation("Thread '{0}' @ {1}", threadName, ms);
    }

}
```

And the file

> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#2' @ 14
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#1' @ 18
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#2' @ 15
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#1' @ 18
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#1' @ 13
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#2' @ 12
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#1' @ 12
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#2' @ 14
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#1' @ 12
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#1' @ 10
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#2' @ 11
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#1' @ 16
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#2' @ 16
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#1' @ 12
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#2' @ 14
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#1' @ 14
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#2' @ 18
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#1' @ 12
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#2' @ 12
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#2' @ 16
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#3' @ 18
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#1' @ 18
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#1' @ 11
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#1' @ 13
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#3' @ 19
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#2' @ 19
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#1' @ 10
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#3' @ 14
> TestCode Information: 0 : Thread 'Thread#1' @ 10

Comment: You can never "prove" thread safety.  (although you can disprove it)  And this is a particularly bad test, because in all likelihood only one thread will try to call `TraceInformation` and the others will be sleeping.

Comment: @BenVoigt Even of I remove sleep (served for randomizing), add more threads, and run longer, there are no conflicts and all traces are written.

Comment: I should clarify that my earlier comment should say "*Tests* can never prove thread safety".  There are of course analyses that work.  I had rephrased halfway through and would up with something inconsistent.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @BenVoigt In this case, will this be fair to say that even thought the listener itself might not be thread safe, using it via `Trace.[]` is thread safe? See my update